# Error upon app archive: Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Im trying to archive our app to appstore. But when i do i'm receiving above error.

Platform: iOS

OS version: 14.4.2

Device manufacturer / model: iphone SE

React Native version (react-native -v): 0.64
xcode version: 12.4

I've been in touch with the guy behind the library react-native-background-fetch and asked him about the issue but i'm thinking there is another reason behind the problem.

This is the first time i'm getting this error so i'm not sure what to do.

#### IDEDistrubution.verbose.log

2021-04-22 14:55:50 +0000 Unable to determine platform from macho "/Users/joakimwennergren/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-04-22/ActiveQuiz 2021-04-22, 16.54.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ActiveQuiz.app/ActiveQuiz-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-background-fetch/ios/RNBackgroundFetch/TSBackgroundFetch.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/TSBackgroundFetch.framework". Failed with error: "Failed to discover platform for executable /Users/joakimwennergren/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-04-22/ActiveQuiz 2021-04-22, 16.54.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ActiveQuiz.app/ActiveQuiz-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-background-fetch/ios/RNBackgroundFetch/TSBackgroundFetch.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/TSBackgroundFetch.framework/TSBackgroundFetch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: I made a video to show how to fix the problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ah9aXs9lTD0 -- the following is a shorter version of the details that are shared in this article: https://christiantietze.de/posts/2021/07/mach-o-0x72613c21-static-library/

---

**Code 0x72613c212 indicates that you are embedding a static library in your app bundle**. That's not necessary, because static libraries already are merged with your app binary at build time by the linker.

Usually, `.framework` bundles are embedded into app bundles and then loaded when you run the app. These are dynamic libs; static libs are already 'in' the app binary, so they don't need to be shipped with the app bundle again. That's why Xcode complains.

#### How to Diagnose

An [Apple Technical Note (TN2435)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html) explains this:

> This [Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21] is caused by placing a static library in a bundle structure that looks like a framework; this packaging is sometimes referred to by third party framework developers as a static framework. Since the binary in these situations is a static library, apps cannot embed it in the app bundle.

From the Technical Note, here's how you can find out if a binary is a static library:

```
file <PathToAppFramework>/<FrameworkName>.framework/<FrameworkName>
```

The output could be like:

```
 Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
 
 <PathToLibrary> (for architecture armv7): current ar archive random library
 
 <PathToLibrary> (for architecture arm64): current ar archive random library
```

For dynamic libraries that do need to be embedded in the app, the output instead says something like `Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

#### How to Fix

If your `file` output looks similar, the solution is to *link* but not *embed:*

[image: link but not embed]

This will include the static library in the build product right away.

Comment: Helped me fix FlutterPluginRegistrant framework as well. Thanks for this command.